# How to setup VPN as Proxy

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, proxy, vpn

I have an PerfectPrivacy VPN connected via the OpenVPN-Network-Manger-Plugin (Ubuntu 12.04.1) and I want to assign a system wide proxy over that VPN.

I have tried proxydriver that should do that automatically, but it works partially.
The browser says that I have the IP of the VPN, but when I tried to send an eMail over SMTP (Port 25), I can´t connect to the mail server.
In our company the smtp server port is closed, but that should be not a problem, when I do that over a VPN, shouldn´t it?

greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up VPN proxy on Ubuntu, you need to make sure that some items
are installed.

> - Make sure that the Network Manager applet is installed.
> - Make sure that the PPTP VPN Connection Manager is installed.
> - Once you have those installed, Click on the network icon in the top bar, choose Edit Connections, and aAdd a new VPN and select the type
>     PPTP. Click Create.
> - Once created click on the network icon in the top bar, and choose VPN Connections<sup>1</sup>

For complete instructions [Read On](http://www.proxy.lu/how-to-set-up-vpn-proxy-on-ubuntu-linux/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[How to set up VPN proxy on Ubuntu](http://www.proxy.lu/how-to-set-up-vpn-proxy-on-ubuntu-linux/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The VPN works fine, so I´m able to connect to the VPN-provider.
When I open my browser and let me show my IP, it says that I have the VPN-IP, but the mail programm wont use the VPN, because in our company the port 25 is closed, so my mail programm can´t connect to the external smtp-server. 

So how can I check that my mail programm is using the VPN connection?

Comment: What E-mail program are you using?

Comment: Outlook with Crossover and Thunderbird, and both is the same problem.

Comment: Can you post the output of `/etc/hosts`, and are you behind a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

You can try proxychains to use the mail app. 
enter in terminal:

```
sudo proxychains thunderbird
```